# Class destructor c++

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I've got a question about destructors in c++.

I've got a class like this :

```
class X {  

private:
    string m_instanceName
    string m_path;
    ConnexionHashMap m_connexions;
    Module** m_moduleType;
    Powerdomain* m_powerDomain;
    Module ** m_father;
};
```

Here are some information concerning ConnexionHashMap :

```
typedef hash_map<const string, Connexion, strptrhash, strptrequal> ConnexionHashMap;

struct Net{
     string name;
     vector<string> connectedPins;
     bool isPin;
};

typedef struct Net Net;

struct Connexion{
    string pin;
    Net* net;
};

typedef struct Connexion Connexion;
```

If I don't want to delete the m_modulType the m_powerDomain and m_father (because they are likely to be referred to by another object), do I have to explicitely write a destructor method ?

I know that string is a standard object and will be destroy by its own destructor, but will the ConnexionHashMap be destroyed by the standard hashmap template destructor or should i delete it manually somehow ?

(also on a sidenote is there an easy way to see how my memory is managed while my program is running on Eclipse cdt ? )

Comment: Quite unrelated comment: In C++ you don't need to explicitly typedef a struct to use it without the struct keyword. A struct is just like a class (but with members declared as public by default).

Comment: it is not related but still useful, thanks for the tips ;)

Comment: Do CDT have a console interface to GDB? If so you can always issue the command `x`, for example `x myptr` or `x/64xb` (show 64 bytes as hexadecimals.) For reference http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memorygdb_56.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I don't want to delete the m_modulType the m_powerDomain and m_father (because they are likely to be referred to by another object, do I have to explicitely write a destructor method?

`m_powerDomain`, `m_father`, and `m_modulType` are pointers and the objects they point to will not be deleted unless you do so explicitly. So, you should write a destructor if you want them to be deleted, otherwise they need not.

> I know that string is a standard object and will be destroy by its own destructor, but will the ConnexionHashMap be destroyed by the standard hashmap template destructor or should i delete it manually somehow ?

It is not that `std::string` are standard object that will make them deleted automatically, but the fact that you are including a `std::string` in your class as a member, so the string is physically allocated inside of your object memory and when this one is deleted the former is also (without need of specifying anything in the destructor).

All the same, `m_connexions`, which is included as an object member, not pointer, will be automatically deleted by the destructor, no need to do anything.

(also on a sidenote is there an easy way to see how my memory is managed while my program is running on Eclipse cdt ? )

you can use a profiler like valgrind or any other you find available...

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid any problems here by just using [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) (`std::shared_ptr` in C++0x) for objects that are shared. It uses reference counting to keep track of references to the object, and deletes the objects once the last reference is gone.

As for your questions, all member objects that are not pointers or references will be destroyed when the containing object is destroyed. That includes your hash-map

Comment: @Christian: I have added an answer. Also, if you think something should be a comment rather than an answer, flag it as *not an answer*.

Comment: that could be interesting and helpful for further development. Do you have a link for a detailed example of how that cam be used ?

Comment: @djfox: I added a link to the documentation of `boost::shared_ptr`. This should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables in a class will be deleted automatically when the class is deleted (even without an explicit destructor).

A user-defined destructor is used to delete pointer-held variables, and free resources held by the class.

Answer (score 2):

The hash_map is deleted since it is a member of the class X. The objects that are addressed with pointers are not deleted, you will have to write a destructor, if you need to delete these objects.

Comment: and that will be a recursive destruction ? ie it will automatically delete the Connexion which is in the map right ? (just to clear things up)

Comment: The hash_map destructor will delete the Connexion objects it owns. The Connexion destructor will delete the contained string member. Pointers don't have destructors. If the Net object is owned by the Connexion object, you need a destructor else (the Connexion has only a weeak pointer) it's sufficient to rely on hash_map distructor.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic principles:

- The destructors of *all* non-static
  member objects will be called in the
  destructor of your object. 
  Regardless of whether you define a
  destructor or not; there is *no* way
  of changing this.
- Destructors of the basic types,
  pointer types and reference types are
  no-ops.  Always.  If you want
  something to happen on them, you must
  provide a user defined destructor,
  and make it happen there.
- Standard containers (and all of the
  pre-standard `hash_map`) contain by
  value; the contents of your
  `ConnectionHashMap` are copies of
  whatever you inserted, and will be
  destructed by the destructor of the
  hash map. (I'm not sure whether or
  how this is relevant to your code.  A
  lot depends on the lifetime of what
  `net` points to, and how that is
  managed.  Depending on the
  application and the design, it
  *might* make sense to make `Connection::net` a
  `boost::shared_ptr`.  *Might*: it's
  not a foregone conclusion that this
  is a good idea.)